# How to create custom server control in asp.net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

With new ASP.NET 4.5 in VS 2013 I do not see project template for creating server control. Does any one have idea how to create custom control in asp.net 4.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of creating a Custom Server Control in ASP.Net.

All depends on your requirements - inherit from [WebControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [CompositeControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositecontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or existing Server Control.

If you are looking for a template, go to `Web > Web Forms Server Control`.

[image]

***FYI:*** Creating a Custom Server Control requires some degree of experiences. If you are new to ASP.Net, I'll suggest you to look at [User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

### Update: How to Create Web Forms Project in VS 2013

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of visual studio you are using? I do not see this template on VS 2013.

Comment: It is Visual Studio 2013 - Web Forms Project. I update the answer with screenshots.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find project template instead of new item